# What is the range of White colour in RGB?

Tags: colors, rgb

I want to exclude range of white colours (all type of whites) based on RGB in my code.

For example, something like:

```
if(redColorValue < 230 && greenColorValue < 230 && blueColorValue < 230)
{
  //It's not white colour
}
else
{
  //It's white colour.
}
```

Comment: What programming or markup language are you looking to get this done with?

Comment: What do you actually need? The range values or how to implement it? If you want to know the values you can google it, if you want to know how to implement it, tell us what you have attempted and where it has gone wrong.

Comment: I am looking for range, i know how to implement the logic. I am thinking of a way to find that this RGB values is whitish in colour and i will have condition to avoid it in my code.

Answer (score -2):

White needs to have the greatest value of all rbg. that is:
R = 255, G = 255, B = 255.

any value that falls below the given absolute is not considered as absolute white.

Comment: May be more detail will help you to answer my question further. I want to show a background from a RGB which is dynamic coming from server only if it is not white (Off white, snow white, all type of whites). I have white text over that background which will not be visible if background is also white. So i want to define a range RGB for whites in which case i will show some other color as a backgorund so that white color text is visible.

Comment: The beast way is to go for range R = 217, G = 217, B = 217 and can add a text shadow for readability.